# UPDATE annual changes with discontinuous dates

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update, intervals, missing-data

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257763/1382306) has shown me how to get annual changes from data:

```
UPDATE values_table as a
join  values_table as b 
ON b.date_sampled = DATE_SUB(a.date_sampled, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
set a.annual_change = a.sample_value - b.sample_value
```

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187063/1382306) has shown me how to find the closest date to an `INTERVAL` (relative to `NOW()` with 3 results, in this question's case):

```
SELECT event_id FROM Table ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( EVENT_START_DATE, NOW() ) ) LIMIT 3
```

How can the two be combined to get annual rates of change when the dates have holes, `SELECT`ing the closest date to the desired `INTERVAL`?

---

I finally had a chance to try Gordon's answer, but I'm getting `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'vt.date_sampled' in 'where clause'`.

I also tried to do a subquery based upon the second answer above after `ON b.date_sampled =`, but it gives `Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'SELECT date_sampled FROM values_table ORDER BY ABS( DATE_SUB(a.date_sampled, INT'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL makes it hard to reference the update table in the `update` statement, but it is possible using subqueries.

I think of the "nearest date one year ago" as a good candidate for a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE values_table vt
    set vt.annual_change = vt.sample_value - 
                           (select sample_value
                            from (select sample_value, date_sampled
                                  from values_table vt2
                                  where vt2.date_sampled <= DATE_SUB(vt.date_sampled, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
                                 ) t
                            order by date_sampled desc
                            limit 1
                           )
```

I would think that you would actually want the date that is at least a year old.  But if you want the closest date, the same idea works:

```
UPDATE values_table vt
    set vt.annual_change = vt.sample_value - 
                           (select sample_value
                            from (select sample_value, date_sampled
                                  from values_table vt2
                                  where vt2.date_sampled <= DATE_SUB(vt.date_sampled, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
                                 ) vt2
                            order by ABS( DATEDIFF(vt.date_sampled, vt2.date_sampled))
                            limit 1
                           )
```

Comment: This is the closest date _before_ one year earlier. Couldn't the date closest to one year earlier be after it?

Comment: @Barmar . . . You are right.  That is what the OP asked for.  Just in my experience, when doing year-over-year comparisons, I would normally want at least one year.

Comment: sorry to come back so late, but I keep getting `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'vt.date_sampled' in 'where clause'`